# Updating name on github through git

Tags: git, github

very new to git and GitHUB, but I have come across a problem which I can't seem to solve. Though not that important at this stage, it's bugging me!

I had my name spelled wrong in git (when I initially started my project and used git config global user.name "Enter Name".

So when I pushed my local repository to GitHub, I ended up with the wrong name on the remote repository - e.g. instead of correct spelling "Enter Username" I realised it's something like "Entre Usename".

I went to my local repository and set this right again through git config global user.name. I proceeded by deleting the repository on GitHub, removing the URL from git (git remote remove origin) and essentially started from the beginning.

So went through a process like this:

Created a new repository on GitHub (same URL as before)
Went back to git and typed:
-git remote add origin (URL)...
-git push origin main

All seems well. The repository gets posted to GitHub...but, the name is still spelled wrong as before and not quite sure what is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to reset the author for all the old commits, basically rewrite the repository history.

Comment: The name is associated with each commit in the Git history. Are you looking to change history? Does this question cover it? [How do I change the author and committer name/email for multiple commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/3266847)